# Combining two different types of graphs in Holoviews using addition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews

I am trying to combine 2 different type of graph. Both the graphs have different x and y axis and that's how it should be. I have to send the plot in an combined way only. Below is what I tried and failed. Any workarounds?

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd

height_sub = 500
width_sub = 400

linechart1 = hv.Curve([(1,2,'crust'), (3,4,'moon'), (4,9, 'mars')])
bubbled1 = hv.Curve([(10,'blue'), (78,'pink')])

linechart1.opts(
    line_color='lightblue', 
#     size=10,
    width=width_sub,
    height=height_sub, 
#     color='lightblue',
#     show_grid=True
)

bubbled1.opts( 
    line_color='black', 
    size=5,
    width=width_sub,
    height=height_sub,
    color='blue',
#     show_grid=True
)
bubbled1 +linechart1
```

But caught up in error stack

```
~\.conda\envs\pyenv\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in _options_error(cls, opt, objtype, backend, valid_options)
    415 
    416         if matches:
--> 417             raise ValueError('Unexpected option %r for %s type '
    418                              'across all extensions. Similar options '
    419                              'for current extension (%r) are: %s.' %

ValueError: Unexpected option 'size' for Curve type across all extensions. Similar options for current extension ('bokeh') are: ['fontsize'].
```

Is there any workaround possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` is not a style option for `hv.Curve` use `line_width` instead if you want thicker lines.

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")

height_sub = 500
width_sub = 400

linechart1 = hv.Curve([(1,2,'crust'), (3,4,'moon'), (4,9, 'mars')])
bubbled1 = hv.Curve([(10,'blue'), (78,'pink')])

linechart1.opts(
    line_color='lightblue', 
    line_width=10,
    width=width_sub,
    height=height_sub, 
    invert_axes=True
)

bubbled1.opts( 
    line_color='black', 
    line_width=5,
    width=width_sub,
    height=height_sub,
    color='blue',
)

layout = bubbled1 + linechart1
layout.opts(shared_axes=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually i dnt want to mix x,y of curve with x,y of points chart. Is it possible to plot graphs with their own individual axis values ?

Comment: Yep! Just specify `shared_axes=False` on the `hv.Layout` object. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks bro. This is awesome.

Comment: Man seem like you the deal. Can you tell me more thing that can we interchange x and y axis in holoviews?

Comment: Just need to pass `invert_axes=True` as an option to the curve you would like to change the axes to. I'll update my answer with an example.